# Background properties not working on safari web broswer

Tags: html, css

I am having problems with Mozilla browser.

Below properties working on Mozilla but not in safari. How can i use same code in both browser. I have tried this code for both browser

```
background: url("../img/side_line.png") no-repeat scroll 3% 50% / 10px auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

but below properties working on safari but not in Mozilla

```
background: url("../img/side_line.png") no-repeat ;
background-position-x: 3%;
background-position-y: 50%;
background-size: 8px;
```

Comment: Can you explain what `3% 50% / 10px auto` means?

Comment: @Justinas - "If one of the properties in the shorthand declaration is the background-size property, you must use a / (slash) to separate it from the background-postion property" - W3Schools

Comment: 3% 50% is position of background and 10 px is the size of background iamge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
background:url(../img/slide_line.png) 3% 50% no-repeat; 
background-size:8px auto;
```

Comment: wow that's great solution.
Thank you so much for the make it easy for me .

Comment: happy to be helped :)